# Rename multiple file with special characters in Fedora

Tags: regex, sed, file-rename

I have several hundred files in the below format:

```
'[animalpics.com][977]bluejays.png'
'[animalpics.com][9]lions.jpg'
'[animalpics.com][99]colts.jpg'
```

I would like to rename all the files to just the description and file type:

```
bluejays.png
lions.jpg
colts.jpg
```

I have tried rename but it doesn't seem to like the command I'm using:

```
rename  's/[animalpics.com][*]//g' *.*
```

How can I edit my command to rename these files? I also have install **mmv** but it's not as intuitive as I thought.

Comment: This just returns an empty line and nothing is changed. Not sure what's happening. @oguzismail


`[jacoby@localhost Downloads]$ rename 's/.*]//' *.*`
`[jacoby@localhost Downloads]$ `
`

Comment: I think you need to escape the opening brackets with backslash to have sed treat them as literal brackets instead of character classes

Answer (score 0):

`rename 's/^.*\]//' *`

Demo:

```
$ls -1
'[animalpics.com][977]bluejays.png'
'[animalpics.com][99]colts.jpg'
'[animalpics.com][9]lions.jpg'
file.txt
$rename 's/^.*\]//' * 
$ls -1
bluejays.png
colts.jpg
file.txt
lions.jpg
$
```